# Binary Search loop

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I have to do a binary search for a names directory in typescript, if the name is in the array the code works properly but if the name it's not in the array it became in an infinite loop.

Can somebody help me? Please!
This is the code:

```
var initialArray = ['Diego', 'David','Mauricio']
var sortedArray = initialArray.sort()
function search(find) {
    var leftLimit = initialArray[0]
    var leftLimitIndex = initialArray.indexOf(leftLimit)
    var rightLimit = initialArray[initialArray.length - 1]
    var rightLimitIndex = initialArray.indexOf(rightLimit) 
    var pivotIndex = 0 
    var index = -1 
      while (compare(leftLimit, rightLimit)) {
        pivotIndex = Math.floor((leftLimitIndex + rightLimitIndex)/2) 
        console.log(pivotIndex) 
        if (initialArray[pivotIndex] == find) {
            index = pivotIndex 
            break 
        }
        else {
            if (compare(initialArray[pivotIndex], find)) {
                leftLimitIndex = pivotIndex + 1 

            }
            else {
                rightLimitIndex = pivotIndex - 1 
            }
        }
        console.log(initialArray[pivotIndex]) 
    }
    console.log("Result: "+initialArray[index]) 
        return initialArray[index] 
}
function compare(leftLimit, rightLimit) {
    var r = (leftLimit < rightLimit  ? -1 : 1) 
    if (r < 0) {
        return true 
    }
    else {
        return false 
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure that `left>=0` and `right<length` and stop if it does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youare not taking in account the limits index which change and at the end you dont know if you have not more options to search or if the findTerm doesnt exits at all.
You only need to change the follow line

```
while (compare(leftLimit, rightLimit) && leftLimitIndex <= rightLimitIndex) {
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you so much!! :) That was the problem!

Comment: Great! So you can mark my answer as correct. Regards,